# How to refresh AngularJs Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I am trying to refresh angular js kendo grid and no solution is working for me. I tried most of the solutions suggested in the forums.

Here is my HTML code

```
<tab heading="Transactions (Exception)" data-ng-controller="ExceptionSearchResultsController as exceptionSearchResults" data-ng-show="exceptionSearchResults.hasResults">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="exceptionSearchResultsGrid" data-kendo-grid ="exceptionSearchResults" data-k-options="exceptionSearchResults.gridOptions" data-show-no-results data-show-active-filters data-k-rebind="exceptionSearchResults.gridOptions"></div>
    </div>
</tab>
```

Here is my controller code

```
function initDataWatch() {
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return exceptionDataService.reportData();
            }, function (newValue) {
                viewModel.dataRecords = newValue.records || [];

                viewModel.gridOptions = {
                    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: viewModel.dataRecords,
                        pageSize: 15,
                        sort: { field: "dateCreated", dir: "asc" }
                    }),
                    pageable: {
                        pageSizes: [15, 50, 100],
                        pageSize: 15,
                        input: true
                    },
                    height: 575,
                    columns: viewModel.columns,
                    columnMenu: true,
                    reorderable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    groupable: true,
                    navigatable: true
                };
            }, true);
        }
```

viewModel.dataRecords is coming from the service call and I can see data on the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to access the datasource of your grid and set a new datasource after the data has changed.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setDataSource

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-fetch

Comment: Thanks It worked.

However loading for the first time I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDataSource' of undefined"

Comment: for the first time grid was undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to reload your grid.

```js
$("#kgrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/UrUSO)**

Comment: I have already tried this. I get TypeError: viewModel.gridOptions.dataSource.read is not a function

Comment: Try with $scope. `$scope.gridOptions.dataSource.read()` and bind the view as `gridOptions`

Comment: $scope.gridOptions = viewModel.gridOptions;
I can see new data in $scope.gridOptions.dataSource.data

$scope.gridOptions.dataSource.read() is still throwing not a function error

Comment: This should fix your issue.Check out this [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UrUSO).

`$("#kgrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();`